# How can we prove for the following intervals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We define half-infinite intervals as follows:

$(a, ∞) = \{x ∈ R : x > a\}$.

$[a, ∞) = \{x ∈ R : x ≥ a\}$.

Prove that

1. $(a, ∞) ⊆ [b, ∞) ⇔ a ≥ b$,
2. $[a, ∞) ⊆ (b, ∞) ⇔ a > b$.

Comment: What are your ideas? How would you show that a set is a subset of another?

Answer (score 1):

$1)$

$i)$ $(a, \infty) ⊆ [b, \infty) \Rightarrow a \geq b$.

If $a<b$ then $(a,b)\neq\emptyset$ and clearly $(a,b)\cap[b,\infty)=\emptyset$. On the other hand $(a,\infty)=(a,b)\cup[b,\infty)$. So there exists $x\in (a,\infty)$ such that $x\not\in [b,\infty)$, just take $x\in(a,b)$. Therefore, $(a,\infty)\not\subseteq [b,\infty)$.

$ii)$ $a\geq b \Rightarrow (a, \infty) ⊆ [b, \infty)$.

$$x\in(a,\infty)\Rightarrow a<x<\infty \overset{a\geq b}{\Longrightarrow} b\leq a< x <\infty \Rightarrow b\leq x <\infty \Rightarrow x\in[b,\infty).$$

So, $(a, \infty) ⊆ [b, \infty)$.

Item $2$ is totally analogous.